# Google Colab: Change python environment from 3.9 to 3.8

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Since the last update from Colab, my code that ran on python 3.8 is not working anymore. I'm trying to switch back to python 3.8 and here's what I tried:

`!sudo apt-get update !sudo apt-get install python3.8 python3-pip !alias python=/usr/bin/python3.8 !. ~/.bashrc`

Then I ran
`!python --version`

It's still showing me
Python 3.9.16

It seems like I was not able to change the python environment nor the system python version.

The same code ran perfectly fine on terminal, which gives me Python 3.8.10. But the not working on the jupyter Notebook.

I wonder if there's any setting in the Colab Jupyter Notebook that's preventing the change of system python version? And is there a way to fix this?

Althernatively,  I also tried
`!sudo update-alternatives --config python3`
And then I manually choose the python version. This changes the python --version, but the system python is still not changing. Hence I'm having problem importing pacakges I installed in python3.8's path.

Comment: In the long run, the best solution is actually to upgrade your code to work with python version to 3.9. What wasn't working in Python 3.9 ?

Comment: Thanks, Nathan! ( It's a custom package that was written for python3.8. )

Comment: And what is the error message when porting it to 3.9 ?